# Simple physical quantity measurement unit parser for Java

Tags: java, parsing

I want to be able to parse expressions representing physical quantities like

```
g/l
m/s^2
m/s/kg
m/(s*kg)
kg*m*s
°F/(lb*s^2)
```

and so on. In the simplest way possible. Is it possible to do so using something like [Pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) (if such a thing exists for Java), or should I use more complex tools like Java CUP?

**EDIT:** To answere MrD's question the goal is to make conversion between quantities, so for example convert g to kg (this one is simple...), or maybe °F/(kg*s^2) to K/(lb*h^2) supposing h is four hour and lb for pounds

Comment: ANTLR? http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Home

Comment: You might want to take a look at a fairly old attempt to interpret physical quantities, the [Pixelmed UCUM Toolkit](http://www.dclunie.com/pixelmed/software/UCUM/). The toolkit utilizes ANTLR. Have a look at the Javadoc for more details. I cannot say anything about its level of completeness, though.

Comment: What exactly is your goal here? How do you mean "parsing" ? Do you mean it should interpret something like **10m/s + 2m/s** and evaluate it to **12m/s** or perhaps
something like **m/s*kg*s** and evaluate to **m*kg** ?
Though sometimes it may not sound like much, clarifing your goal can help you get there!

Comment: without brackets (which are infrequent) "m/s*kg*s is an example of unclear semantics.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust Sorry, for the initial mistake. By the way, why do you think m/s*kg*s is unclear? Proceeding from left to right I don't find it unclear.

Comment: Because some people will use the slash to separate everything , i.e. m/(s*kg*s). You and I may not like it, but that sort of thing happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is harder than it looks. (I have done a fair amount of work here). The main problem is there is no standard (I have worked with NIST on units and although they have finally created a markup language few people use it). So it's really a form of natural language processing and has to deal with :

- ambiguity (what does "M" mean - meters or mega)
- inconsistent punctuation
- abbreviations
- symbols (e.g. "mu" for micro)
- unclear semantics (e.g. is kg/m/s the same as kg/(m*s)?

If you are just creating a toy system then you should create a BNF for the system and make sure that all examples adhere to it. This will use common punctuation ("/", "*", "(", ")", "^"). Character fields can be of variable length ("m", "kg", "lb"). Algebra on these strings ("kg" -> 1000*"g" has problems as kg is a fundamental unit.

If you are doing it seriously then ANTLR (@Yaugen) is useful, but be aware that units in the wild will not follow a regular grammar due to the inconsistencies above.

If you are REALLY serious (i.e. prepared to put in a solid month), I'd be interested to know. :-)

My current approach (which is outside the scope of your question) is to collect a large number of examples from the literature automatically and create a number of heuristics.

Comment: Also there are "local" abbreviations, and other non-standard unit modifies such as 10 g = 1 dag (by SI) = 1 dkg (commonly) See [SI prefixes in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix)

Comment: M is for mega and m for meters, but still some people could not know/pay attention to this. Yet another case is F, is it Farad or Fahrenheit? (Correct notation for Fahrenheit is °F, but still...). Anyway since it would be inserted in some software, I will suppose the user will make a little effort and avoid bizarre or simply wrong notations

Comment: @Paolo Agreed! The linguistic context helps ("we heated it to 100F" can be parsed to resolve it. But it requires a parser (e.g. http://http://chemicaltagger.ch.cam.ac.uk/) which provides this

Comment: I gave it +1 for pointing out something I didn't think about, yet my wish was to keep things as simple as possible :)

Comment: @Paolo. It's only simple if *you* have created a self-consistent system. In which case define your grammar and semantics and use ANTLR. Anything in the real world is not simple, however much it seems so.